# Suggested close reason missing on review audit

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, review-audits

While going through the review queue on Server Fault, I ran across [a review which asked me:](https://serverfault.com/review/close/73273)

> Should this question be closed as ? (more)

It should indeed have been closed as **not constructive**. Upon clicking Close, I was informed that it was a review audit and I passed.

I believe there is a bug here in that the audit did not show a close reason in its query.

Edit:

[image: bug screen]

Comment: I've had this same bug happen to me several times. I've added a recent image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed now. This bug was occasionally surfacing when a *known bad* post was selected for audit, and all its close votes had already "expired".